# How do I remove the URL protocol and slash from user input in PHP

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

Example user input

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/topic/
http://example.com/topic/cars/
http://www.example.com/topic/questions/
```

I want a PHP function to make the output like

```
example.com
example.com/topic/
example.com/topic/cars/
www.example.com/topic/questions/
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use an array of "disallowed" terms and use [`strpos`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to dynamically remove them from the passed-in URL:

```
function remove_http($url) {
   $disallowed = array('http://', 'https://');
   foreach($disallowed as $d) {
      if(strpos($url, $d) === 0) {
         return str_replace($d, '', $url);
      }
   }
   return $url;
}
```

Comment: @blur This will return gracefully if the string does not contain any of the "disallowed" strings.

Comment: What if the URL is something like:  `http://domain.com/topic/https://more/`?  That's a valid url with a valid path, but this approach would mangle it in a way that (I think) the OP wouldn't have intended.

Comment: @Lee Good point, I updated my answer to take care of that case.

Comment: I really don't think this is the best approach.  How do you account for other schemes?

Comment: @Madbreaks The OP asked about how they can remove only those two schemes. We can make this more extensible, but it's not necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 153):

`ereg_replace` is now deprecated, so it is better to use:

```
$url = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $url );
```

This removes either `http://` or `https://`

Comment: This could have been simply an edit [of the original answer (ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165330/367456).

Comment: I'd suggest to remove all possible protocols with `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+://"` instead

Comment: This is bad practice and only works as long as the protocol never changes.

Answer (score 31):

I'd suggest using the tools PHP gave you, have a look at [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

It sounds like you're after at least `host` + `path` (add others as needed, e.g. `query`):

```
$parsed = parse_url('http://www.domain.com/topic/questions/');

echo $parsed['host'], $parsed['path'];

    > www.domain.com/topic/questions/
```

Cheers

Comment: what about fragment and query? the poster did not explicitly say to remove those.

Comment: @KimStacks I assume op can figure that out from what I posted, but in the spirit of being pedantic I've updated my answer slightly.

Comment: $parsed['host'].$parsed['path'] gives //www.domain.com/topic/questions/

Answer (score 10):

Create an array:

```
$remove = array("http://","https://");
```

and replace with empty string:

```
str_replace($remove,"",$url);
```

it would look something like this:

```
function removeProtocol($url){
    $remove = array("http://","https://");
    return str_replace($remove,"",$url);
}
```

Str_replace will return a string if your haystack (input) is a string and you replace your needle(s) in the array with a string. It's nice so you can avoid all the extra looping.

Answer (score 6):

Wow. I came here from google expecting to find a one liner to copy and paste!

You don't need a function to do this because one already exists. Just do:

```
echo explode("//", "https://anyurl.any.tld/any/directory/structure", 2)[1];
```

In this example, explode() will return an array of:

```
["https:", "anyurl.any.tld/any/directory/structure"]
```

And we want the 2nd element. This will handle http, https, ftp, or pretty much any URI, without needing regex.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

If you want a function:

```
function removeProtocols($uri) { return explode("//", $uri, 2)[1]; }
```

EDIT: See user comment from Harry Lewis... this is my favourite way to do this now.

Comment: It absolutely won't return that array, the deliminator won't remain, you'll get "https:" for the first item. This answer also assumes that there are no double slashes anywhere else in the string and also assumes that the url has a protocol in the first place when that could be unknown.

Comment: @Shardj edited (we don't use the first array element though!). It makes no assumptions about protocol. If you used input "//anyurl.any.tld/any/directory/structure" it will output that string minus the double slashes.

This answer does assume the input is equivalent to all of the examples given in the OP. It won't process urls with additional double slashes (I actually didn't know that was a valid URI!).

Comment: To solve the possibility of additional double slashes you can use `explode()`'s 3rd argument, `$limit` like so: `explode('//', $url, 2);`

Comment: Love it. Simple and effective for what I need to do.

Comment: Of course, if there aren't any double-slashes at all, explode() will return an array containing a single item (the input string), so youd probably just want to always take the last element, i.e.: `last(explode('//', $url, 2));`

Answer (score 5):

You can remove both https and http in one line using a *regular expression* with [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```php
fn (string $url): string
    => preg_replace('~^https?://~', '', $url);
```

- [Regular expression: `~^https?://~` Test and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/VbHBag/1) (regex101.com)

Comment: @wlarcheveque: Please see the reference Q&A on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004/367456 (also a recent edit should make the comment superfluous, we could delete both comments then).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parse url Functionality of PHP. This will work for all Protocols, even ftp:// or https://

Eiter get the Protocol Component and substr it from the Url, or just concatenate the other Parts back together ...

http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me, short one.

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// user input
$url = 'http://www.example.com/category/website/wordpress/wordpress-security/';
$url0 = 'http://www.example.com/';
$url1 = 'http://www.example.com/category/';
$url2 = 'http://www.example.com/category/website/';
$url3 = 'http://www.example.com/category/website/wordpress/';

// print_r(parse_url($url));
// echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$removeprotocols = array('http://', 'https://');

echo '<br>' . str_replace($removeprotocols,"",$url0);
echo '<br>' . str_replace($removeprotocols,"",$url1);
echo '<br>' . str_replace($removeprotocols,"",$url2);
echo '<br>' . str_replace($removeprotocols,"",$url3);

?>
```