# Checking validity url in php

Tags: php, http, url

Нi guуs. I russian php noob.
I have the following code:

```
if($rr['site']) echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.$rr['site'].'" class="">'.$rr['site'].'</a>';
```

Need to make a valid of the user a url HTTP there or not. Otherwise it outputs - `http://http://siteurl`

Prompt me how to do it? pliz

Maybe, there is a solution - [How do I remove http, https and slash from user input in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357668/how-do-i-remove-http-https-and-slash-from-user-input-in-php)
but i need an example with my code.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Use the function in the example you posted. `$site = remove_http($rr['site'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the opposite. Instead of removing `http://` or `https://` and then adding it again, I would just check if the string starts with `http://` or `https://`, and add `http://` only if it doesn't.

Something like:

```
if($rr['site']) {
    $url = preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $rr['site']) ? $rr['site'] : 'http://'.$rr['site'];
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.$url.'" class="">'.$url.'</a>';
}
```