# How do I remove http, https from string in php

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

Example user input

```
http://domain.com/
hTTp://domain.com/Cars/
hTtp://www.domain.com/pAge/
```

I want a php function to make the output like

```
domain.com
domain.com/Cars/
www.domain.com/pAge/
```

Let me know :)

Comment: Use `str_replace()` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: str_repleace does not work when user's input is hTtp

Comment: Try `preg_replace` then, including what you tried. Or, `str_ireplace()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php which is for case-insensitive. It will match `http` and `htTp` etc.

Comment: @GiorgiLazashvili you can use str_ireplace() to make it case insensitive http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove http, https and slash from user input in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357668/how-do-i-remove-http-https-and-slash-from-user-input-in-php)

Comment: how can i use str repleace to *://     ?

Comment: George Garchagudashvili, there are no answer for my question

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regular expressions here, just use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$url = 'hTtp://www.domain.com/pAge/';
$url = str_replace( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME ) . '://', '', $url );
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get an array with the different parts of the url and rebuild it as a string any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a regex, with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
`$converted = preg_replace('#^h+t+p+s+?://#i', '', $stringtoprocess);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way might be

```
echo str_replace('//','',strstr($url, '//'));
```