# how to send url with get method

Tags: php, forms, get

i have a form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="sample.php">
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

when i sumbit form with an url(like https://google.com) my link is:

```
site.com/sample.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

but i want send Formed url like this (without https://):

```
site.com/sample.php?url=google.com
```

how i can do this?

Comment: Its actually pretty okay that you can't do this: you're (apparently accidentally?) preventing Cross Site Scripting.

Comment: excuse me. I edit my question @Loek. I want url like this site.com/sample.php?url=google.com

Comment: Ok. So do you only want to remove http:// and https:// or you want totally prevent urlencode for all characters? @Majid

Comment: yes  @AliSheikhpour

Comment: That was perhaps the least useful way to respond to that question...

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357668/how-do-i-remove-http-https-and-slash-from-user-input-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery you can replace `http://` or `https://` with nothing before submit:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   var $input = $(this).find("input[name=url]");
   var cleanValue = $input.val().replace("http://","").replace("https://","");
   $input.val(cleanValue);
});
```